# Windows Phone - Admob in Visual Studio 13 not working

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, admob

i try to implement Admob in my windowsphone app using visual studio 2013 ultimate on windows 8.

When I try to implement the dll I get the error which sais, that I cannot add a refrence to a higher version or implement an incompatible assembly...

When I use the example code I get it working, but only with the error that the namespace is not found (still working somehow) - however, I cannot use the designer anymore until the error is fixed... Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of admob are you using? Which version of Windows Phone does your project target?

Comment: Windowsphone 8 and Admob 6.5.11 - downloaded from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download?hl=de#downloadwp - since my visual studio is on german I cannot post a useful error screenshot...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution and want to provide it to you:

Since the Admob dll was in a zip file I had to unblock it.

Go to unpacked dll -> rightclick -> properties -> Allow / Unblock at the bottom of the file

After this I could ad the reference.